# Android Studio Live Template for Flutter camelCase(String)?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

Trying to setup a livetemplate for Flutter which is this:

```
S.of(context).$END$$lowerCaseName$ $lowerCaseName$":$SELECTION$
```

Where lowerCaseName is camelCase(String). But when I run it, I get an extra " right after $END$

For example, if I select "test string" in my code and surround with the live template, instead of getting this:

```
String test = S.of(context).TestString TestString":"test string";
```

I get this:

```
String test = S.of(context)."TestString "TestString":"test string";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `$SELECTION$` value is the whole string you select, including quotes. So you have to strip them somehow. I'd suggest using `groovyScript()` - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-template-variables-dialog.html, http://bartololeo.blogspot.com/2014/01/idea-12-how-to-write-live-template-with.html. For example, the following function specified as *expression* for `$lowerCaseName$` should do the thing:

```
camelCase(groovyScript("_1.replace('\"', '')", SELECTION))
```